# How can I use python to identify a certain state of a graphic on the screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics, computer-vision

Let me make my question more clear. I am making a program where the program simulates a certain set of keypresses in a video game when a certain 'graphic' fully 'charges' up. This graphic is basically a vertical bar that fills up all the way to the top. How can I use python to interpret this graphic and return some info when the bar is visually fully charged up. The position of the graphic on the screen is always consistent and the state of the bar when it is indeed fully charged up, is always the same.

Comment: You will have to probably use a library like OpenCV to capture your screen and analyse the image.

Comment: Yes, but how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to achieve that is to use the `ImageGrab` module from Pillow.
And then use some pixels in the snapshot to determine if the bar is filling.

Pillow docs - https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageGrab.html